# Populate TreeView - children node with subnode

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I need to populate treeview from database took look like:

Parent
      - Children
                - Subchildren

There are three tables. One that consist 'Parent' data, second for 'Child' data and third for 'Subchilds'

For now I made loading data for 'Parents' and 'Childrens':

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtProjekti = objDB.dbGetTable("SELECT * FROM tblProjekti");
        DataTable dtAktivnosti = objDB.dbGetTable("SELECT * FROM tblAktivnosti");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtProjekti);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtAktivnosti);
        ds.Relations.Add("childrens", dtProjekti.Columns["OznakaProjekta"], dtAktivnosti.Columns["OznakaProjekta"]);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            treeProjekti.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow masterRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                TreeNode masterNode = new TreeNode(masterRow["OznakaProjekta"].ToString(), 0, 1);
                treeProjekti.Nodes.Add(masterNode);

                foreach (DataRow childRow in masterRow.GetChildRows("childrens"))
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(childRow["NazivAktivnosti"].ToString());                          
                    masterNode.Nodes.Add(childRow["IdAkt"].ToString(), childRow["NazivAktivnosti"].ToString(), 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to populate treeview" + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

How to solve problem for loading subchildrens?

Answer (score 0):

the subchild node is a child node of "childNode".  you should just need another foreach statement with the subchild  data after you add the childNode to the parent in your code above .

Comment: I've already tried that, but another problem it making relation with second and third database table. It doesn't allow me to make new dataset and populate with second and third table and make relation between them.